# Can I use vi keybindings in the Chrome/Safari JavaScript console?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, vi

I'd like to be able to use `vi` keybindings in the Chrome JavaScript console (cmd-opt-J in OS X, ctrl-shift-J elsewhere, I think).  Basically, I want to be able to hop around and edit like I do in `vim`.

I use `vi` keybindings all over the terminal, such as `irb`, `bash`, `python`, `mysql`, `sqlite3`, etc. and I find them great for quick interactive development.  (All those programs use GNU readline, so they respect my `~/.inputrc`.)  Currently, Chrome is one of the few places I can code but not use `vi` keybindings.

Any extensions or settings I can use for this?

Comment: Do you want this for OS X or Linux?

Comment: OS X, in my case.

Comment: I might even be happy if `node` used GNU readline... but it doesn't.  :(

Answer (score 1):

[Vi Input Manager](http://www.corsofamily.net/jcorso/vi/) can do this for all Cocoa applications. I've used it a few years ago. I don't know if it works on Snow Leopard though (if you're using SL, you didn't say) unfortunately.

---

Alternatively, you can experiment using the Cocoa [Key Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Concepts/KeyBindings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008900-BAJCDFFI) system. There's a [vi-line key bindings](http://aldebaran.armory.com/~zenomt/macosx/KeyBindings.html) file that you could try to use.